# MVC in iphone apps

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller

can somebody explain me the basics of mvc in iphone apps?

I see the template classes, but how do they communicate?

does UIView send events to the Controller? or does the model send events?

what of the template files is the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model shouldn't be concerned with the view. The same holds true for the view, it should be decoupled from the model and not really have direct access to it, despite the fact it will be displaying information from the model for the user to see and interact with. The controller acts as intermediary between models and views.

In Apple's words, "A **controller** object interprets user actions made in **view** objects and communicates new or changed data to the **model** layer. When **model** objects change, a **controller** object communicates that new model data to the **view** objects so that they can display it."

Comment: thx, all answers hav been helpful for me, since its a broad topic

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend the iTunesU, Stanford University series titled "Developing Apps for iOS (HD)" by Paul Hegarty.

Lesson 1 discusses MVC and lesson 2 demonstrates it.

These lessons are free, and well worth a view if you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

From Jeff Atwood's *Excellent* blog "Coding Horrors":

> Like everything else in software
>   engineering, it seems, the concept of
>   Model-View-Controller was originally
>   invented by Smalltalk programmers.
>
> More specifically, it was invented by
>   one Smalltalk programmer, Trygve
>   Reenskaug. Trygve maintains a page
>   that explains the history of MVC in
>   his own words. He arrives at these
>   definitions in a paper he published on
>   December 10th, 1979:
>
> Models Models represent knowledge. A
>   model could be a single object (rather
>   uninteresting), or it could be some
>   structure of objects.
>
> There should be a one-to-one
>   correspondence between the model and
>   its parts on the one hand, and the
>   represented world as perceived by the
>   owner of the model on the other hand.
>
> Views A view is a (visual)
>   representation of its model. It would
>   ordinarily highlight certain
>   attributes of the model and suppress
>   others. It is thus acting as a
>   presentation filter.
>
> A view is attached to its model (or
>   model part) and gets the data
>   necessary for the presentation from
>   the model by asking questions. It may
>   also update the model by sending
>   appropriate messages. All these
>   questions and messages have to be in
>   the terminology of the model, the view
>   will therefore have to know the
>   semantics of the attributes of the
>   model it represents.
>
> Controllers A controller is the link
>   between a user and the system. It
>   provides the user with input by
>   arranging for relevant views to
>   present themselves in appropriate
>   places on the screen. It provides
>   means for user output by presenting
>   the user with menus or other means of
>   giving commands and data. The
>   controller receives such user output,
>   translates it into the appropriate
>   messages and pass these messages on to
>   one or more of the views.

The best way to understand this (like many core concepts of iOS programming *cough* HIG *cough*), is to read Apple's documentation and *try* it. Here is a good design pattern overview (including MVC) for beginners, including a tutorial: [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH1-SW1)

Comment: I have seen that Reenskaug quote a time or two and the funny thing is it never really helped to clarify, but actually muddled my understanding of MVC. I comprehend what he is saying, but the way he says it is so poorly worded that it doesn't clarify the concept like you'd think he could. Just an observation.